# Is there a tool that describes updated dependencies in Composer?

Tags: composer-php

You do a `composer update` and get a list of a few updates:

```
- Installing cakephp/cakephp (3.0.12)
- Installing cakephp/debug_kit (3.1.10)
- Installing cakephp/bake (1.0.13)
- Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.3.1)
- Updating admad/cakephp-jwt-auth dev-master (9a20b56 => e1bb793)
  Checking out e1bb793e334b11bdaa19fb653f4b89a4544524f5
```

Being a conscientious developer, you want to know what's new in CakePHP 3.0.11 and Bake 1.0.13 and all of the rest, to make sure that you're not introducing breaking changes into your project (or if so, that you go fix them right away). You start to dig through Packagist, follow its links through to Github, then find the release tags. Sure, it doesn't take too incredibly long for a project that has only a few dependencies, but what about one with a few dozen?

Which leads to my question -- is there a tool that could automate this process, to automatically give you links to the release notes for the new versions that composer just pulled down for you? Or, even better, displays that information right in your command line?

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking for a tool or off-site resource is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: When I asked the question, I'd never heard of the "recommendation question" off-topic reasoning. I find this reasoning to be utterly asinine. Stack Overflow is where programmers talk about using Composer. Why not ask about it here? However, in the spirit of following the rules, how might you suggest that I alter the question to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a Composer Plugin called **Composer Changelogs**.

It gives a summary of the modified packages with links to release and compare urls.

In other words: after an update or install you get links to the release tag, the release notes and the commits difference between the last and the new release tag for each package.

https://github.com/pyrech/composer-changelogs

[image: Demo]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like this plugin didn't even exist when I asked the question, so Googling it at the time wouldn't have helped. I love the concept of pasting the output of this plugin into the commit message for the composer.lock update.

Comment: Glad i could help :) Yes, the plugin is brand new. I remembered your question, while running into the plugin on Github. Its probably the best way to get a decent update description of dependencies into the commit message of the lock file. - I imagine one improvement: a CLI command for this plugin, which simply commits the log file using the message automatically `--commit-lockfile`. Then the copy/paste/edit/commit message steps would fall away.